# Linq Any() throws error: String was not recognized as a valid boolean

Tags: c#, mysql, linq, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm building a ASP.NET core app using the core MVC. Since I'm planning to host it on the Linux environment I've decided to go with a MySQL database. I've managed to setup the DB connection and the whole ApplicationDBContext. The LINQ DB queries work fine, up until a point where Any() query is used.
Then a following exception occurs:

> An exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: String was not recognized as a valid Boolean.

Here's an example code. This method is called from Configure method of Startup.cs:

```
public async static void Initialize(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
        var services = app.ApplicationServices;
        var dbContext = services.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>();

        var countResult = (dbContext.Users.Count() > 0); // true
        var anyresult = dbContext.Users.Any(); // exception
}
```

The automatically translated SQL query looks like this:

```
SELECT CASE
    WHEN EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM `AspNetUsers` AS `a`)
    THEN ('1') ELSE ('0')
END
```

This returns either '1' or '0' and system tries to convert this type of string into a boolean, but it fails and throws the above exception.
I tried to go around it by not using Any() at all, but then I've found out that some of the built in functions are getting this exception as well, e.g.:
`userManager.AddToRolesAsync`

And here's my ConfigureServices method:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    var sqlConnectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DataAccessMySqlProvider");

    // Add EF services to the services container.
    services
        .AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseMySQL(
                sqlConnectionString,
                b => b.MigrationsAssembly("MyAssembly")
            )
        );

    services.AddIdentity<User, IdentityRole>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

    // Add framework services.
    services.AddMvc();
}
```

Is there any way this can be fixed?

Here's my *project.json* file:

```
"dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.0.1",
      "type": "platform"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies": "1.0.0",
    "SapientGuardian.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql": "7.1.9"
  },
  "tools": {
    "BundlerMinifier.Core": "2.0.238",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },
  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },
  "runtimeOptions": {
    "configProperties": {
      "System.GC.Server": true
    }
  }
```

Comment: Can you show the bit of code that generates that query ?

Comment: Add your Linq statement too, it may be useful

Comment: Hey, added the sample code into the description.

Comment: You are using Select 1. And Linq will try to convert this to Boolean.

Comment: "and system tries to convert this type of string into a boolean" Are you saying LINQ-to-SQL is doing this automatically?

Comment: Sounds like MySQL provider bug because the same works in SqlServer.

Comment: @IanKemp exaclty. You can see the code sample and translated SQL which is logged in my VS output window.

Comment: @RadoKoňuch: Does `dbContext.Users.Any(u => true)` works as possible workaround? Other then that, I suggest writing an issue ticket http://bugs.mysql.com/ (choose "Connector / .NET" category). The Oracle MySQL provider can be called pre-alpha at best. No migrations, no scaffolding.

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded the package **SapientGuardian.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql** to version 7.1.10 where the author fixed the issue with boolean conversion and it started working.